# External table in Snowflake with CSV format

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load data from CSV file (comma separated) from Azure Blob to Snowflake External table .

Now the cell content has comma separated values due to which data is getting jumbled up.
There is no possibility that the CSV file can be changed.

What should then be the approach ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE ANALYTICSLAYER.AN_MEDALLIA_P.EXT_DIM_APP_TRAINING_SURVEY
(
    "Col1"                              varchar  AS (value:c1::varchar),
    "Col2"                              varchar  AS (value:c2::varchar),
    "Col3"                              varchar  AS (value:c3::varchar),
    "Col4"                                  varchar  AS (value:c4::varchar),
        "Col5"                              varchar  AS (value:c5::varchar),
        "Col6_DATE"                     varchar  AS (value:c6::varchar),
        "Col7"                          varchar  AS (value:c7::varchar)
  
)
WITH 
LOCATION=@ST_TESTAZURE_P
AUTO_REFRESH = true
FILE_FORMAT = 'FF_TEST_CSV_P'
PATTERN='.*DIM_TEST_FILE_DATA.csv';
```

Comment: Do the fields that contain commas have delimiters round them (e.g. double quotes)? If they do then you need to add the FIELD_DELIMITER to your file format definition (if it's not already there). If they don't then your csv file is not valid and it is not processable - there is no way to tell if a comma is a field delimiter or part of the contents of a field

Comment: You need to give us some sample data. You can load this without changing it, but we can't help if you keep us blind. Please also define what you mean by "jumbled up".

Comment: This has more to do with the csv data format in your file rather than Snowflake. Snowflake has native support for CSV with all options (skip header, field_delimeter, etc). It would be a good idea to add sample data and how it appears in Snowflake so someone can help